# Compare cell names using InStr with wildcard

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to use the `InStr` function to return the cells which match Sheet1.Cells(i,4) with Sheet2.Cells(i,3) and place the match on Sheet2.cells(i,10).

I get results which do not match. [Match Description File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j3YR6Et_O2LphpjPREJHDNJSk45PgWNz/view?usp=sharing)

```vb
Sub CompareSheetsInstr2()
    Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
    Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    
    '*********** ASSIGN INDEX NUMBER **************  
    
    ' Set the worksheet objects for both sheets
    Set Sheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Sheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")     
    
    For i = 2 To Sheet2.UsedRange.Rows.Count            
          
        If InStr(1, LCase(Sheet1.Cells(i, 4).Value), LCase("*" & Sheet2.Cells(i, 3).Value & "*")) > 0 Or _
          InStr(LCase(Sheet2.Cells(i, 3).Value), LCase(Sheet1.Cells(i, 4).Value)) > 0 Then          
          
    '*********** MATCH BY INDEX NUMBER **************
                'If Sheet1.Cells(j, 3) = Sheet2.Cells(i, 4) Then           
                
                ' If there is a match, replace the value in Sheet2 with the value in Sheet1
                Sheet2.Cells(i, 10).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value                
                
            End If
        
        Next i
    ' Next j
    MsgBox "Comparison complete!"
End Sub
```

---

Modified this code and seems to work great. Let me know if you notice any wrong.

```
Sub CompareSheetsInstrModified()
Dim oSheet1 As Worksheet
Dim oSheet2 As Worksheet
Dim oSheet3 As Worksheet
Dim headers() As Variant
Dim a As Long, i As Long, j As Long, RowCnt As Long, RowCnt2 As Long
Dim arr1, arr2, res(), res1()
Dim arr3, arr4, res2(), res4()
Dim sKey1 As String, sKey2 As String
Dim sKey3 As Variant, sKey4 As String
headers() = Array("DATE", "NUMBER", "PAYEE", "ACCOUNT", "AMOUNT", "MEMO")
' Set the worksheet objects for both sheets
Set oSheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set oSheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set oSheet3 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
' Load data into array
arr1 = oSheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
arr2 = oSheet2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
arr3 = oSheet3.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value

' Store matching result in an array
RowCnt = UBound(arr2)
RowCnt2 = UBound(arr3)
ReDim res(1 To RowCnt, 1 To 1)
ReDim res1(1 To RowCnt, 1 To 1)
ReDim res2(1 To RowCnt2, 1 To 1)
ReDim res3(1 To RowCnt2, 1 To 8)
ReDim res4(1 To RowCnt2, 1 To 8)
' Loop through all rows in Sheet2

For i = LBound(arr2) + 1 To UBound(arr2)
'For i = LBound(arr3) + 1 To UBound(arr3)
    sKey2 = LCase(Trim(arr2(i, 3)))
    sKey3 = (arr2(i, 2))
    If Len(sKey2) > 0 Then
        ' Comparing all rows in Sheet1
        For j = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
            sKey1 = LCase(Trim(arr1(j, 4)))
            If Len(sKey1) > 0 Then
                ' Matching
                If InStr(sKey1, sKey2) + InStr(sKey2, sKey1) > 0 Then
                    ' Update the output
                    res(i, 1) = arr1(j, 1)
                    res1(i, 1) = arr1(j, 2)
                    res2(i, 1) = arr2(i, 2)
                    arr3(i, 1) = Abs(arr3(i, 5))
                    res3(i, 1) = arr3(i, 5)
                    res4(i, 1) = arr3(i, 8)
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    End If
    ' Debug.Print "=match result=", i, j
Next i
' Drop data to column J (modify as needed)
oSheet2.Cells(1, 12).Resize(RowCnt, 1).Value = res
oSheet2.Cells(1, 13).Resize(RowCnt, 1).Value = res1
oSheet2.Cells(1, 10).Resize(RowCnt, 1).Value = res2
oSheet2.Cells(1, 14).Resize(RowCnt, 1).Value = res3
oSheet2.Cells(1, 11).Resize(RowCnt, 1).Value = res4
' Add Header
For a = LBound(headers) To UBound(headers)
    Sheet2.Cells(1, 10 + a).Value = headers(a)
    Next a
'Exit For
'MsgBox "Comparison complete!"
```

End Sub

Comment: `Instr()` doesn't support wildcards. eg. the result of `InStr("abcd","*bc*")` is 0. `Dim Sheet7 As Worksheet` should be `Sheet2`. Please share sample data in OP, it's helpful to understand your case.

Comment: @taller Here's the link to the file https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j3YR6Et_O2LphpjPREJHDNJSk45PgWNz/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=108615520453907025015&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: @taller this code works great. What exactly is going on within the codeing? I'm still at the beginners level. Thank you.

Comment: I have updated my reply w/ some notes. Hope it is helpful for you.

Comment: I have an additional question, If you notice the "Prime Video Channels amzn.com/bill WA        09/13" text lines on Sheet2. Thoses all have dates  in column 3 and amounts in column 4.

Comment: Both D17 and D18 in Sheet1 are blank. So it's no way to match it. eg. Update D18 w/ `Prime Video` and run code again.

Comment: @taller I have an additional question, If you notice the "Prime Video Channels amzn.com/bill WA        09/13" text lines on Sheet2. Those all have billing dates in column 3 and amounts in column 4. On sheet1 there are the following descriptions in column1 which I will move/place into column 4, "AMC, Best TV,Cinemax,EPIX, Lifetime, MovieSphere, Paramount, Screambox, Showtime, STARZ. How do I include that data within the match?

Comment: You simply need to run the code again to refresh the output after making any updates to column 4 in Sheet1.

Comment: @taller The problem is on sheet2 column3 all read "Prime Video Channels amzn.com/bill WA        09/13" with the amount in sheet2 column4. They should be assign a video channel name such as "AMC, Best TV,Cinemax,EPIX, Lifetime, MovieSphere, Paramount, Screambox, Showtime, STARZ. Based on the date in sheet2 column3 and amount. Like if Prime Video Channels .... 09/13  with amount 10.99 then cell name should equal Cinemax. Look at the table I included the link in Sheet3 example.

Comment: Please update your post with matching logic for date and amount.

Comment: @taller Here's what I'm trying to do, your help is greatly appreciated. [link}(https://docs.google.com/document/d/1e33d9xjmuWFZlkMDLFheOhgIJ7b8w68HNo55MQXE228/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @taller I had noticed using your orginal code that Sheet2 row 57 PAYPAL didn't match Sheet1, what happened?

Comment: Sheet1 D209 is `PAYPAL INST XFER WEB ID`. It doesn' meet matching condition with Sheet2 row 57.

Comment: I believe you could revise my code to complete the "#1. Compare". Afterward, you can create a separate post for the second part.

Comment: @taller As I've stated before, I'm just a novice, your approach on this is totally different than I had expected. I'm not familiar with some of the methods use and what's exactly going on. I've been stepping through your code line by line, examining how and what to change to reach my objective.

Comment: @taller The PAYPAL no matching and a few others still has me wondering but I can change the text in sheet 1 so the match can work. Not sure how long it may take me to modify your code to accommodate the other instructions. I've been working on this the last few weeks and now the next banking statements are just about to come in. I'll guess I continue to do this manually until I get a better understanding of Excel VBA. Thanks for your time.

Comment: For PAYPAL issue, you need to update Sheet1 D209 instead of the code.

Comment: Does updated code get the expected result for `#1. Compare`?

Comment: @taller Modified this code and seems to work great. Let me know if you notice any wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To locate the corresponding row, the code examines each transaction against `all` the rows in `Sheet1`.
- If any of the values in `Sheet1.Cells(i,4)` or `Sheet2.Cells(i,3)` are blank, the row is skipped.
- The term `Sheet1` could refer to either a sheet name or a sheet codename. It is advisable to avoid using it as a variable name to prevent ambiguity.
- **Note:** Keep in mind that `Instr("abc","")` will yield a result of `1`

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CompareSheetsInstr2()
    Dim oSheet1 As Worksheet
    Dim oSheet2 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, RowCnt As Long
    Dim arr1, arr2, res()
    Dim sKey1 As String, sKey2 As String
    ' Set the worksheet objects for both sheets
    Set oSheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set oSheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    ' Load data into array
    arr1 = oSheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    arr2 = oSheet2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    ' Store matching result in an array
    RowCnt = UBound(arr2)
    ReDim res(1 To RowCnt, 1 To 1)
    ' Loop through all rows in Sheet2
    For i = LBound(arr2) + 1 To UBound(arr2)
        sKey2 = LCase(Trim(arr2(i, 3)))
        If Len(sKey2) > 0 Then
            ' Comparing all rows in Sheet1
            For j = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
                sKey1 = LCase(Trim(arr1(j, 4)))
                If Len(sKey1) > 0 Then
                    ' Matching
                    If InStr(sKey1, sKey2) + InStr(sKey2, sKey1) > 0 Then
                        ' Update the output
                        res(i, 1) = arr1(j, 1)
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next j
        End If
        ' Debug.Print "=match result=", i, j
    Next i
    ' Drop data to column J (modify as needed)
    oSheet2.Cells(1, 10).Resize(RowCnt, 1).Value = res
    MsgBox "Comparison complete!"
End Sub
```

[image]

---

> Update for `#1. Compare`

- Achieving this with an array is more efficient, but it might require additional time for you to become familiar with the code.
- Given that your data set is not large, the following code does not consume too much time, making it a convenient way for you to maintain the data mapping.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CompareSheetsInstr3()
    Dim oSheet1 As Worksheet
    Dim oSheet2 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, RowCnt As Long
    Dim arr1, arr2
    Dim sKey1 As String, sKey2 As String
    ' Set the worksheet objects for both sheets
    Set oSheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set oSheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    ' Load data into array
    arr1 = oSheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    arr2 = oSheet2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    ' Loop through all rows in Sheet2
    For i = LBound(arr2) + 1 To UBound(arr2)
        sKey2 = LCase(Trim(arr2(i, 3)))
        If Len(sKey2) > 0 Then
            ' Comparing all rows in Sheet1
            For j = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
                sKey1 = LCase(Trim(arr1(j, 4)))
                If Len(sKey1) > 0 Then
                    ' Matching
                    If InStr(sKey1, sKey2) + InStr(sKey2, sKey1) > 0 Then
                        ' Modify data mapping as needed
                        oSheet2.Cells(i, 13) = oSheet1.Cells(j, 1)
                        oSheet2.Cells(i, 14) = oSheet1.Cells(j, 2)
                        oSheet2.Cells(i, 11) = oSheet2.Cells(i, 2)
                        oSheet2.Cells(i, 15) = Abs(oSheet2.Cells(i, 4))
                        oSheet2.Cells(i, 12) = oSheet2.Cells(i, 7)
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next j
        End If
        ' Debug.Print "=match result=", i, j
    Next i
    MsgBox "Comparison complete!"
End Sub
```